# html 5 video is not auto playing on iphone

Tags: iphone, video, video-streaming, html5-video, mp4

I have video and i have embedded it in website but somehow it's not playing automatically in iPhone. Given below is the code i am using but video is not playing automatically when we visit the page. Anyone can you please guide me what to do. I have search this problem on google but i have not find any solution about that.

Code i am using:

```
<video autoplay muted>
<source src="midia/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="midia/video.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Diagnose:

One important thing to note is that "iDevices" doesn't support all the varieties of mp4. Here is a small list about MPEG-4 and H.264 supported varieties.
According to Apple official website, iPad or iPhone 4S is only compatible with H.264 or MPEG-4 video format with the following specifications:
•   If it is H.264 video, it should meet: up to 1080p, 30 frames per second, High Profile level 4.1 with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps, 48kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats;
•   If it is MPEG-4 video, it should meet: up to 2.5 Mbps, 640 by 480 pixels, 30 frames per second, Simple Profile with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps per channel, 48kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats;
But there are some forums saying that in fact, the iPad specifications are these:

iPad Supported Video Format:

H.264 video (up to 720p, 30 frames per second; main profile level 3.1 with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps, 48kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats)
•   MPEG-4 video, up to 2.5 Mbps, 640 by 480 pixels, 30 frames per second, Simple Profile with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps, 48kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats.

Cause:

(Web Issue) - happens because the iPad/iPhone doesn't have an HTML5 player that works so well as it should yet.
1.  (Local Issue) - happens for a completely different cause, which is the supported resolution of the mp4 videos on "iDevices".